# Google Reader Api mark All item As read

Tags: api, url, google-reader

This is how my url looks be:

```
https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/mark-all-as-read?s=http://www.campionatoseriea.net&ts=1345114937
```

I can't understand why it doesn't work! I'm successfully logged in.

* EDIT ***

```
https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/mark-all-as-read?s=feed/http://www.campionatoseriea.net/feed&ts=1346843394
```

I tried also this query but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including the token parameter (T).

`https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/mark-all-as-read?s=feed/http://www.campionatoseriea.net/feed&ts=1346843394&T=//cDr2ct8ynZS2I-P4x4cn1A`

[This document](http://undoc.in/googlereader.html#api-0) describes how to get a token.

Answer (score 1):

```
?s=http://www.campionatoseriea.net
```

In the s you must pass the feed ID, not url. Here is example:

```
?s=feed/http://www.gsmarena.com/rss-news-reviews.php3
```